# Setting Up of MySQL Table for Multiple Choice Questions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz online. I want to store all the potential questions in a MySQL database. Currently I'm thinking of one column being 'Question ID', one column being 'Question', one column being the answers in this form: ['A','B','C'], and the last column being the answer. If I add all four possible options in one column will I eventually be able to extract them and display them as individual questions? What format should I use to do that?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: make a table with one to many relation.

Comment: Your question is too broad, but in a nutshell, you need to have multiple related tables.  Learn about relational database design and normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Well your approach is not incorrect if you are thinking to store all the data in one table but it would be best if you create multiple tables for better management and flexibility as

> Question Table :- Contains column id and question .
>
> Answer Table :- Contains column id,answers  Ques_Ans table : Contains
>   columnid,ques_id,ans_id,is_answer

Comment: The id column in your third table is redundant